# flutter toast Background have same color when I change it how could I solve

Tags: flutter

When use flutter toast, Color of message appear with gray background how to solve it and background color is green

```dart
     Fluttertoast.showToast(
                     msg: state.loginModel.message,
                     toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                     gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                     timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                     textColor: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 16.0);
```